# Как разместить input по центру

Tags: html5, bootstrap

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>

<form class="justify-content-center ">
  <div class="container">
    <div
        class="form-group col-md-5 text-center">
      <label><b>Username</b></label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>
      <label><b>Password</b></label>
      <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw"
             required>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
      <button class="btn" type="submit">Login</button>
      <button class="btn" type="submit">Register</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Использую bootstrap 4 , как разместить поля для ввода по центру?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153234/center-a-column-using-twitter-bootstrap-3 тут тебе уже накидали вариантов) Способов очень много=)

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в css для класса "form-group" свойство "margin: 0 auto"

```css
.text-center {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Home</title>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
  
</head>
<body>

<form class="justify-content-center ">
  <div class="container">
    <div
        class="form-group col-md-5 text-center">
      <label><b>Username</b></label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>
      <label><b>Password</b></label>
      <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw"
             required>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
      <button class="btn" type="submit">Login</button>
      <button class="btn" type="submit">Register</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```